# Do bears have killer instinct?

Tags: zoology

For example, all big cats have killer instinct.

They go straight for the throat or neck of their prey, killing it before consuming.

I've seen videos of bears and wolves hunting prey. I've never seen any where they bite the throat or neck deliberately.

Bears just bash their prey till they die or eat them alive.
Wolves eat their prey alive when the prey literally exhausted all of their energy.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Are you asking "why do some species kill by biting the throat and some use other strategies?" A beat beating its prey to death still sounds like an instinct to kill to me...

Answer (score 1):

A bear usually kills its prey by biting it on the back or neck. The bear uses his forepaw to strike very hard, usually breaking the prey's spine so this is why usually his killing instinct is on the back part of a prey. Bears also bite their prey on the snout.
this information can be found at the end of this article: http://www.largecarnivores.fi/species/brown-bear/bears-diet-and-hunting-behaviour.